# Possible delta-v savings with solar sails for reaching a Mercury-like orbit

Tags: dyson-ring, solar-sails

I want to send the parts of a Dyson swarm to a heliocentric orbit with the average orbital radius equivalent to that of Mercury. I've heard that in terms of delta-v Mercury is a hard place to reach and I want to use solar sails to decrease the required delta-v. **How effective would solar sails be in reducing delta-v requirements?**

Edit: There has been some confusion around this question. I am starting from Earth. The spacecraft would have chemical rockets on board. I just want to know if solar sails could be used at any point in the mission to decrease the amount of fuel needed. Whenever the solar sails can't effectively perform the necessary maneuvers, the chemical rockets will take over. Furthermore, I accidentally said that the solar sails could "reduce the delta-v requirements" when I meant to say that they can supply some of the delta-v.

Comment: Are you you talking about going from a *superior* planet, say Earth, to an *inferior* one? I'd have to double check, but I think the solar sail only has an advantage if the attitude control system uses less delta-v to maintain an orthogonal vector relative to the solar wind during the sail's braking maneuver and consequent in-spiral. Otherwise, you might as well use that delta-v to make the burn to Mercury.

Comment: Pedantically solar sails do zero to reduce delta-V requirements. They can supply delta-V. How much delta-V is dependent on sail size/area.   Please clarify your question, since currently you are asking a non-answerable question.

Comment: @BMF Solar sails do not use the solar wind at all. They use light pressure. Electric sails use the solar wind.

Comment: @AvunJahei Solar sails with their edge facing the Sun's rays encounter the particles in the solar wind and experience drag in the direction of their orbit. Electric sails would be a better option, though.

Comment: @BMF The solar wind is completely irrelevant for solar sails because the pressure of the particles is several orders of magnitude less than the pressure of the sun light. Solar wind and sun light both go in the same direction - away from the Sun, so what you say does not even make sense.

Comment: @AvunJahei We are going from a *superior* orbit to an *inferior* orbit, towards the Sun. You cannot use a solar sail to "tack"/maneuver inwards towards the Sun. See [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/370/can-you-tack-against-the-sun-using-a-solar-sail). You instead have to rely on drag force from the medium to deplete your orbital energy.

Comment: No, that does not work. You cannot use the "drag force of the medium" with a solar sail. The force is so tiny that it is irrelevant. You actually can use the photons to slow down your orbital speed, but not without increasing the eccentricity of your orbit.

Comment: @AvunJahei Drag force depends on the size of the sail, and it won't be negligible for very large and thin ones. I didn't say it would be a speedy process, but we're not talking eons without change either. To change the trajectory significantly, the sail needs to encounter a good fraction of its own mass in the medium, which isn't inconceivable. Lowering perihelion and increasing eccentricity may not be what OP wants for their Dyson swarm, unless the payloads can complete the burn. They're better off with electric sails, anyway.

Comment: @BMF A solar sail has been used to go from Earth to Venus. This has been done by IKAROS 2010. No drag needed, just need to direct light to slow down orbit.

Comment: @BMF The solar wind would not even exert any drag force. The force of the solar wind goes in the same direction as the solar rays. Everything the solar wind can do on your sail the solar rays can do as well, just about 1000 times better.

Comment: @AvunJahei the difference between thrusting off of light rays and thrusting off of drag from the medium is that the "drag thrust" can match the vector of travel while thrust from light pressure can't (it fades to zero in the limit as the sail tilts edge-on to the Sun). The only reason I'm saying any of this is because the OP wants a *circular* orbit near Mercury with *lightsails*. Using light pressure, you can dip down into the orbit of Mercury, but only with drag or some other radial thrust can you circularize and match its orbit.

Comment: @GaultDrakkor the IKAROS probe did a Venus fly-by. It could not circularize with Venus, which is what OP is asking for in order to assemble a Dyson sphere. A lightsail can use light pressure to increase its eccentricity (to do a Venus fly-by from Earth) but can't circularize without additional thrust.

Comment: @BMF And why exactly does the pressure of the solar wind not fade to zero when the light pressure fades to zero?

Comment: @AvunJahei why would it fade to zero? The sail has forward momentum through a transverse stream of particles, some of those particles are bound to be "too slow" and deflect off the surface, stealing some of the sail's momentum. There's nothing stopping a lone proton from stepping in front of the sail's disk <1 mm away and getting smacked aside/deflected, being "too slow" to traverse the whole face of it in time. Because of that, there'll be a pressure differential between the front and back of the sail, acting as a drag force.

Comment: @BMF Since the speed of the solar wind particles is much faster than the orbital speed of the sail you would not simply get a "drag". You could slow down orbital velocity but would get an increase in orbital eccentricity. Exactly the same you can do using photon pressure, just 1000 times or so more efficiently.

Comment: @AvunJahei Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137877/discussion-between-bmf-and-avun-jahei).

Answer (score 2):

> How effective would solar sails be in reducing delta-v requirements?

Pedantic note: the delta-V requirement can't be reduced by changing your propulsion mechanism... if you want to get into a different orbit your speed has to change. What solar sails *do* give you is the ability to change your delta-V without being limited by your onboard fuel and reaction-mass reserves.

A Mercury-like orbit is difficult to get to with simple chemical rocketry, because whichever way you slice it you need to change from a heliocentric orbital velocity of about 30km/s at Earth to one of about 48km/s at Mercury. This is impractical thing to achieve with chemical rockets, and whilst a decent solar-powered plasma rocket might manage it, a nice solar sail is a much simpler option with no need for high power electrical systems or reaction mass tanking, etc.

The good news is that a solar sail can be used for any orbital manoevers you'll need. There have been a bunch of plans around a [Solar Polar Orbiter](https://sci.esa.int/web/trs/-/36025-the-solar-polar-orbiter) mission which involves sticking a probe in a polar orbit around the Sun at about .5 AU radius. Moving from an equatorial orbit to a polar orbit requires a *lot* of delta-V... about 1.4 times the orbital velocity of the initial orbit. That's an extra 60km/s or so, and the fact that it was considered entirely practical for a solar sail back in the dark ages of 2006 shows that you should have no problems. Here's a visualization of the mission trajectory from [Solar Sail Trajectory Optimization for the Solar Polar Imager (SPI) Mission](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225019754_Solar_Sail_Trajectory_Optimization_for_the_Solar_Polar_Imager_SPI_Mission):

[image: Visualization of solar polar orbiter mission trajectory, showing solar sail temperature, orbital radius and inclination. Orbit changes from 1AU to .48AU and inclination from 7° to 75°, with the solar sail reaching a peak temperature at aphelion of 520K]

This shows you that you can:

- drop the perihelion of your orbit
- circularize your orbit
- change the inclination of your orbit

All without the need to expend any reaction mass or burn fuel.

The optimized "hot" trajectory described in that paper lists a flight time of nearly 5 years. Merely getting to a Mercury-like orbit without a dramatic change in inclination will be dramatically faster, but solar sail accelerations are sufficiently fiddly to calculate that I'm not going to try and work out how much faster. If you're impatient, a conventional Hohmann transfer will take you under 4 months. The solar sail is inevitably going to take much more than a year.

---

Note that solar sails needn't be the only game in town... they were of interest to the solar-polar people because we can more or less build them right now.

By the time you're making a Dyson swarm, technology will probably have marched on a bit. Consider the possibility of other things, such as [magnetic sails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_sail) which might be able to give you substantially more acceleration without the difficulties of needing a vast sheet of sail material. You might also use something like a [magbeam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagBeam) to provide an initial boost, which could dramatically shorten the time to final orbital insertion, without needing giant sails or deep-future ultratech.